# how to use Spring security with Custom java class/ custom spring framework's class?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

My requirement is as below:

In our application the user's credentials are validated against the database(not using spring security since it is a legacy application) for the first time. If the user is a valid user, he will be logged into the application. Once the user logs into the application he can make few rest calls. Now, I want to once again validate the user's credentials by using spring security before making any rest call. Here, the challenge is we should not redesign the database schemas. We need to use a stored procedure which validates the user. This particular stored procedure returns an error message if authentication fails, otherwise nothing is returned. There are no roles defined in this case. Just simple authentication using a stored procedure. Now, I want to accomplish this whole thing by spring security. May be writing a java class/ custom spring framework's class and in which the stored procedure is called and using that class in spring security configuration files. Can anybody suggest ideas on how to start up with please?

I have implemented AuthenticationProvider. The following is the *security.xml.

```
  <http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/*" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
</http>

    <authentication-manager >
    <authentication-provider ref="csAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

But, the security framework is looking for roles. In my case there are no roles defined. As I said earlier, the user is authenticated for the first time without using spring framework. If the user wants to make any rest call, the spring security needs to re authenticate the user. It doesn't mean that the user needs to re enter credentials. The user's credentials are available in the rest call/request since he is already authenticated. The only thing needs to be done is I need to use the credentials by using request and re validate using the stored procedure. of course, using AuthenticationProvider may be a good idea, but the parameter "Authentication authentication" of the authenticate(Authentication authentication) method is not useful for me since I need to call my own stored procedure call again. for time being, I did not used the Authentication  object, but instead used the stored procedure calling code in the authenticate() method. But, strangely, authenticate() method is not getting called. I am surprised and in confusion. Does any body has any ideas on where I am doing wrong?

Comment: It would be great if anybody can share the pseudo code for my problem.

Comment: Please describe what you're doing more specifically. You say that "the security framework is looking for roles". What does that mean? What code is actually being called? Also explain how you want the Spring Security to authenticate the user if there are no credentials available and you don't expect the user to provide any. If you expect to just use the same HTTP session as when they logged in, then when you authenticate the user you need to create a security context which Spring Security can use for future requests.

Comment: Luke,Thanks!, "the security framework is looking for roles": meaning as per my requirement, there is no need to verify roles. The user's entered credentials are stored in the request object when the user logs for the first time. I need to use those credentials and re authenticate using spring security(via stored procedure call). It is okay for me to use the same HTTP session when the user logged in. Could you please guide me how to get the same http session, creating Spring Security context and to re authenticate as per the said requirement. it would be great if you can share some pseudo code.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to implement an Authentication Provider. Here's a pretty simple example that I think you could adapt to call your stored procedure.

http://danielkaes.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/custom-authentication-provider-in-spring/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I will take a look at the link posted by you.

Comment: Could you please take look at the edited content and suggest any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own UserDetailsService and configure spring to use it.

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.Initially, I too thought the same. If we implement UserDetailsService, we need to override loadUserByUsername(String username). But, some how , UserDetailsService class is not getting called. If you want to take a look, I will post the code.

Comment: See my comment in rhinds question - a UserDetailsService doesn't do authentication (see [this FAQ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html#faq-what-is-userdetailservice). You are best to implement an AuthenticationProvider directly if you want to encapsulate your own authentication code.

Comment: Thanks Luke for your response. I will try by implementing AuthenticationProvider as you said and let you know if I find any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom UserDetailsService implementation, that will check against the DB.

Here is an example UserDetailsService implementation that does just that:

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        username = username.toLowerCase();
        try {
            Account account = accountService.loadUserAccountByEmail(username);
            if (account == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find email: " + username + "in the DB.");
            }

            List<GrantedAuthority> auths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            for (Role r : account.getRoles()) {
                auths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r.getRole()));
            }
            ApplicationUser user = null;
            try {
                user = new ApplicationUser(new Long(account.getId()), username, account.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, auths);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return user;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username + "not found", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Which I config in code like so:

```
@Override
     protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
     }
```

(you can also see a blog post I wrote about switching from xml to @annotation config for spring security referncing that project here: http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/spring-4-xml-to-annotation-configuration.html)

Comment: The requirement is that a stored proc is used to perform authentication. A UserDetailsService doesn't perform authentication so is not a suitable option.

Comment: Ahh yes. You are right - I read it as the stored proc just grabbing the user data - glossed over the bit about actually authenticating in the DB.

Comment: Luke,Could you please take look at the edited content and suggest any ideas?